# When using browser-sync,why is the browser saying cannot get, while everything seems fine

Tags: browser-sync

This is the screenshot of cmd:

[image]

I wrote

```
browser-sync start --server --files "app\index.html"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot it appears that your project directory is situated in the Desktop folder and is structured as follows:

```
confusion
│
└───app
    │
    └───index.html
```

In which case you could try instructing Browsersync to start a server from the `app` directory. If you `cd` to your folder named `confusion` then run:

`browser-sync start --server "app" --files "app/index.html"`

Note the addition of `"app"` after the `--server` flag.